# Implement hash data structure using a text file

Tags: database, text, hash, hashcode

How can you implement a hash data structure on disk in a simple (txt) file? (Essentially implementing your own simple key-value database). 
I *don't want to read in the whole file* to get the key/value I am looking for. I'd like to store all the data in one file if possible.

One solution would be to take the hash of the string, and then store the hash of the string as a file named with the hashcode, something like:

```
hash('some string') = '5ac749fbeec93607fc28d666be85e73a'
```

so then I store the value 'some string' in a file titled:

```
5ac749fbeec93607fc28d666be85e73a.txt
```

but that means I may have to have thousands of txt files on my filesystem which is not really ideal.

Comment: I did some research - looks like b-tree and b+tree is the way to go? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZjYr87r1b8

Comment: The problem with text files is that they're sequential in nature: to get to the 100th line, you need to read first 99 lines. You don't have to keep all those lines in memory, but you definitely have to read them. The other problem is that your only option for updating the text file is at the end: you can truncate the file, or append to it. But if you want to change something in the middle, you end up having to copy the data to another file. A text file simply is not a good way to store a hash table.

Comment: so what's the alternative, a binary file? can you explain?